# SQL: always return true from `IN` condition

Tags: mysql, sql

How to make `IN` condition always return true just like `WHERE 1`, I tried null but didn't work:

```
WHERE X IN (NULL)
```

Is there a way to alway make `IN` returns true and accept all rows?

return true from something like the following:

```
where X in ("Any value here to alway return true")
```

Comment: Null values require some extra handling. I'd do `where x is null or x in (....)`.

Comment: @jarlh I don't compare with null I need to always return true without care of column value

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is to include the column being compared:

```
where x in (x)
```

However, this does not include `NULL` values.  In fact, there is no way you can make this return true:

```
where NULL in ( . . . )
```

You could revise this to:

```
where coalesce(x, '') in (coalesce(x, '')
```

Comment: Sorry I forget to put column in my question

Comment: There's no way to return true from something like this: `where x in (some thing here)`

Comment: @mwafi . . . If `x` is `NULL`, the expression will always return `NULL` (I could caveat that some databases might have settings that treat `NULL`s differently from standards).  But you can include `x` in the list for non-`NULL` values.

Comment: I don't want to match null in column x, I need the condition to always return true

Comment: @mwafi . . . Maybe you just wand `or 1=1` in the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `LEFT JOIN` :

```
select t.*
from table t left join
     ( . . .  ) tt
     on tt.x = t.x;
```

Comment: I have to use `IN` is there any way to always return true from something like this: `where X in ("Any value here to alway return true")`